Help with identifying full-effects model, mixed-effects model
I am pretty new to conducting mixed-model analyses and need some help in addressing some questions posed by some reviewers. For this experiment, there are two conditions (easy passage, hard passage; this is a repeated-measures & fixed effect). Each condition is presented 10x each to a subject for a total of 20 trials). Furthermore, order of condition is counterbalanced, resulting in two versions of experimental stimuli  (Version; so essentially this creates an independent groups variable, but it is not of theoretical interest). Passage and Subject are random effects. The time to respond to an easy/hard stimulus is measured (RT_target).
Here is my code for models with random intercept only and one with random intercept & random slopes:
#Models random intercept only with Cohens d
m <- lmer(RT_target ~ Difficulty + (1 | Passage) + (1 | Subject) + 
 (1| Version), targetlong); summary(m); Anova(m)

lme.dscore(m, data=targetlong, type="lme4")

##LME Models - random intercept and slope model
#random intercepts and slope model, all one line
m <- lmer(RT_target ~ Difficulty + (1 + Difficulty|Passage) + (1 + Difficulty|Subject) + (1 + Difficulty|Version), 
          targetlong); summary(m); Anova(m)

lme.dscore(m,data=targetlong,type="lme4")


> m <- lmer(RT_target ~ Difficulty + (1 | Passage) + (1 | Subject) + (1| Version), targetlong); summary(m); Anova(m)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']

Here is my output (Note that the random intercept/random slope model is a singular fit):
Formula: RT_target ~ Difficulty + (1 | Passage) + (1 | Subject) + (1 |      Version)
   Data: targetlong

REML criterion at convergence: 9191.1

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0938 -0.6683 -0.1240  0.4936  4.7051 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 234993   484.8   
 Passage  (Intercept)  63099   251.2   
 Version  (Intercept)   6304    79.4   
 Residual             331702   575.9   
Number of obs: 585, groups:  Subject, 30; Passage, 20; Version, 2

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     2094.31     123.61  16.943
Difficultyhard   300.76      47.66   6.311

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
Diffcltyhrd -0.193
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: RT_target
            Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Difficulty 39.825  1  2.777e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> lme.dscore(m,data=targetlong,type="lme4")
                      t       df         d
Difficultyhard 6.310725 535.2918 0.5455241

> ##LME Models - random intercept and slope model
> #random intercepts and slope model, all one line
> m <- lmer(RT_target ~ Difficulty + (1 + Difficulty|Passage) + (1 + Difficulty|Subject) + (1 + Difficulty|Version), 
+           targetlong); summary(m); Anova(m)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: RT_target ~ Difficulty + (1 + Difficulty | Passage) + (1 + Difficulty |  
    Subject) + (1 + Difficulty | Version)
   Data: targetlong

REML criterion at convergence: 9177.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3268 -0.6142 -0.1575  0.4834  4.3494 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name           Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Subject  (Intercept)    204033.5 451.70       
          Difficultyhard  34097.4 184.65   0.28
 Passage  (Intercept)     37975.9 194.87       
          Difficultyhard  39117.3 197.78   0.41
 Version  (Intercept)      4237.4  65.10       
          Difficultyhard    276.4  16.63   1.00
 Residual                313055.6 559.51       
Number of obs: 585, groups:  Subject, 30; Passage, 20; Version, 2

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     2093.33     109.06  19.194
Difficultyhard   302.41      73.32   4.124

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
Diffcltyhrd 0.130 
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: RT_target
            Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Difficulty 17.011  1  3.717e-05 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

I am reporting the random intercept model because of the singular fit warning when I run with random slopes.
Here's how I reported the analysis: “Reaction time for targets were analyzed separately by estimating linear mixed effects models with R (R Core Team, 2020) and lme4 function (Bates et al, 2012). Cohen’s d for was found using the “lme.dscore” function of the EMA tools package (Kleinman, 2017). Targets were analyzed by entering participants and items as random intercepts and difficulty as a fixed effect. All reported analyses are reliable at p ≤ .05.  Reaction time to targets were slower in the hard condition compared to the easy condition, X2 (1) = 39.82, d = .54.”
However, a reviewer is asking that I report the a complete model results. Would the complete model be just the random intercept & random slope model (i.e., the one that resulted in a singular fit)? If this is not the complete model, what would it be? And what does it mean that the model I report produces the same pattern of results as the complete model?
A second reviewer is asking for the model equations. For the random intercept model, would the equation be:
Y ~ Difficulty + (1 + Difficulty|Passage) + (1+ Difficulty|Subject) + (1 + Difficulty|Version)

And for the random-intercept plus slope model, the equation would be:
Y ~ Difficulty + (1 + Difficulty|Passage) + (1 + Difficulty|Subject) + (1 + Difficulty|Version)

So sorry for all the noob questions -- I'm learning LME pretty much on my own and some of the sources are pretty overwhelming.
I appreciate any guidance.

Hi, welcome to CV! 1) Response to your rev.1 question depends on what exactly did you report from the random intercept model, so can you add that info to your question? 2) Rev. 2: typically, equations would refer to the mathematical equations of your models, see e.g. here. 3) as a side note, using a variable with only two levels (like your "Version") is typically not recommended to be used as a random effect - at least 5-6 levels are needed to get reliable random effect estimates.

Thank you. Here's what I reported: “Reaction time for targets were analyzed separately by estimating linear mixed effects models with R (R Core Team, 2020) and lme4 function (Bates et al, 2012). Cohen’s d for was found using the “lme.dscore” function of the EMA tools package (Kleinman, 2017). Targets were analyzed by entering participants and items as random intercepts and difficulty as a fixed effect. All reported analyses are reliable at p ≤ .05.  Reaction time to targets were slower in the hard condition compared to the easy condition, X2 (1) = 39.82, d = .54.”

OK, thanks for letting me know about Version as a random effect

Re: Rev. 1. Your text is very clear, but if that was all you reported, my guess is the reviewer wants a Table with the intercept, fixed effect estimate, its SE, CIs, exact p-value, and all random intercept variances or ICCs. It may help to search for "multilevel model results table" or the like.

Yes, I think you're right. Thank you so much for the feedback!

There are a variety of issues here:

as @Sointu points out in comments, Version probably isn't feasible as a random effect because it only has two levels. You may be confusing nuisance variables (variables not of direct scientific interest) with random effects; they are not always the same (e.g. see discussion here), and in this case you should probably make Version a fixed effect. If you include Difficulty*Version (rather than Difficulty+Version) then you will also be accounting for the possibility of an interaction between order and difficulty.
I'm guessing that your experimental design has 10 'easy' passages and 10 'hard' passages. If so, you shouldn't try to fit random slopes for the Passage random effect, as these effects should be unidentifiable (each passage is either "easy" or "hard", so you can't estimate the variation in the effect of difficulty across passages).
You might want to consider log-transforming your reaction times or using a Gamma response (typically with a log link), as these values often have skewed conditional distributions (take a look at the model diagnostics with the DHARMa package or performance::check_model())
I agree with the commenter that it's hard to guess exactly what the reviewer means by "complete model results".

library(lmerTest)
library(equatiomatic)

dd <- expand.grid(Subject = factor(1:30), Passage = factor(1:20))
subj_vers <- data.frame(Subject = factor(1:30), Version = factor(rep(1:2, 15)))
pass_diff <- data.frame(Passage = factor(1:20), Difficulty = factor(rep(c("easy", "hard"), 10)))
dd <- merge(dd, subj_vers, by = "Subject")
dd <- merge(dd, pass_diff, by = "Passage")
set.seed(101)
dd$RT <- simulate(~Difficulty*Version + (1 + Difficulty|Subject) + (1|Passage),
     newdata = dd,
     newparams = list(beta = rep(1,4), theta = rep(1,4), sigma = 1),
     family = gaussian)[[1]]
fit <- lmer(RT ~Difficulty*Version + (1 + Difficulty|Subject) + (1|Passage),
            data = dd)


if you use the lmerTest package, anova(fit) will give you an ANOVA table, and summary() will give you a coefficient table with p-values etc. (not sure where lme.dscore comes from ...)

equatiomatic::extract_eq(fit) gives you the following (in LaTeX format):
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{RT}_{i}  &\sim N \left(\alpha_{j[i],k[i]}, \sigma^2 \right) \\    
\left(
  \begin{array}{c} 
    \begin{aligned}
      &\alpha_{j} \\
      &\gamma_{1j}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
\right)
  &\sim N \left(
\left(
  \begin{array}{c} 
    \begin{aligned}
      &\gamma_{0}^{\alpha} + \gamma_{1}^{\alpha}(\operatorname{Version}_{\operatorname{2}}) \\
      &\mu_{\gamma_{1j}}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
\right)
, 
\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
     \sigma^2_{\alpha_{j}} & \rho_{\alpha_{j}\gamma_{1j}} \\ 
     \rho_{\gamma_{1j}\alpha_{j}} & \sigma^2_{\gamma_{1j}}
  \end{array}
\right)
 \right)
    \text{, for Subject j = 1,} \dots \text{,J} \\    \alpha_{k}  &\sim N \left(\gamma_{0}^{\alpha} + \gamma_{1}^{\alpha}(\operatorname{Difficulty}_{\operatorname{hard}}) + \gamma_{2}^{\alpha}(\operatorname{Difficulty}_{\operatorname{hard}} \times \operatorname{Version}_{\operatorname{2}}), \sigma^2_{\alpha_{k}} \right)
    \text{, for Passage k = 1,} \dots \text{,K}
\end{aligned}
$$
This isn't perfect (not necessarily the way I would have written it), but it's correct.

Thank you for the help; I really appreciate it. My bad on treating Version as a random effect; I realize it is a fixed effect.  Also, much thanks for the code and equations. I will certainly play around with them!

If this answer solved your problem, you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it. (You're not required to, though - you may want to do some more experimentation before deciding whether to accept.)

I am trying to work with equatiomatic but haven't yet been successful in generating the LaTex format. This is a different issue, so I'll check the problem as solved. Thank you!
